# How does the distance between a light source and a lens affect the beam's intensity?

Tags: optics, lenses

I have a system with a light source, a convex lens, and a light detector. The beam travels from the light source, through the lens (causing a divergence), and into the light detector. The light source can move towards and away from the lens. This changes divergence of the beam and therefore the measured lux in the light detector. How are these quantities (the intensity in lux and light source position in meters) related? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To collect the maximum amount of light you should place the lens so that it will place an image of the source onto the detector surface.

You can do the analysis with basic ray optics and the concept of image magnification.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification#Magnification_as_a_number_.28optical_magnification.29

Answer (score 0):

If the source radiates energy equally in all directions then all the light from the source must pass thought a sphere, centred on the source of radius $L$.  The surface area of the sphere is $4 \pi L^2$.

Let the distance between the source and the lens be $L$.

If the diameter of the lens is $D$ then its surface area is $\frac 1 4 \pi D^2$

So the fraction of the light emiited by the source which goes through the lens is $\dfrac{D^2}{16L^2}$